# Recursion gives me completely wrong answers

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I want to find the number of ways, a given integer X can be decomposed into sums of numbers which are N-th powers and every summand must be unique. For example if X = 10 and N=3, I can decompose this number like that:

10 = 2^3+1^3+1^3 ,but this is not a valid decomposition, because the number 1 appears twice. A valid decomposition for X = 10 and N = 2 would be 10 = 3^2+1^2, since no summand is repeating here.

Now I tried it to use recursion and created the following Python Code

```
st = set(range(1,int(pow(X,1/float(N))))) # generate set of unique numbers
print(str(ps(X, N, st)))


def ps(x, n, s):
    res = 0
    for c in s:
        chk = x-pow(c,n) # test validity 
        if chk > 0:
            ns = s-set([c])
            res += ps(chk,n,ns)
        elif chk == 0:
            res += 1 # one result is found
        else:
            res += 0 # no valid result
    return res
```

I used a set called st and then I recursively called the function ps that includes the base case "decomposition found" and "decomposition not found". Moreover it reduces a larger number to a smaller one by considering only the ways how to decompose a given number into only two summands.

Unfortunately, I get completely wrong results, e.g.

```
X = 100, N = 3: Outputs 0, Expected 1
X = 100, N = 2: Outputs 122, Expected 3
X = 10, N = 2: Outputs 0, Expected 1
```

My thoughts are correct, but I think the Problem is anywhere in the recursion. Does anybody see what I make wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
>>> X = 100
>>> N = 3
>>> int(pow(X, 1/float(N)))
4

>>> list(range(1, 4))
[1, 2, 3]
```

The output is indeed correct *for the input you are feeding it*.

Comment: I forgot the +1 in end of range; now I fixed this and for X=100,N=3 I get now the result 24, for X = 100,N=2 I get 123 and for X=10,N=2 I get 2. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line `res += 1 # one result is found` in conjuction with `res += ps(chk,n,ns)` will make the algorithm add twice.

E.g `X = 10, N = 2: Outputs 0, Expected 1` because:

c=1:

- 10 - 1^2 > 0 -> `res += ps(chk,n,ns)`

c=3:

- 9 - 3^2 == 0 -> `res += 1 # one result is found` ... `return res`

So, in c=3 `res=1` is returned to the c=1 call, which will

`res += ps(chk,n,ns)`, and  `ps(chk,n,ns) = 1`, making `res = 2` and doubling the result expected.

E.g. `X = 29, N = 2`.

29 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2

Solving from bottom to top (the algorithm flow):

c=4 -> `res += 1`... `return res`

c=3 -> `res += ps()` -> `res += 1` -> `res = 2` ... `return res`

c=2 -> `res += ps()` -> `res += 2` -> `res = 4` ... `return res`

But res is supposed to be 1.

Solution: You cannot add `res` to `res`. And you must remove the previous iterated objects to avoid path repetition. Check the solution below (with prints for better understanding):

```py
def ps(x, n, s):
    print(s)
    print("")
    return ps_aux(x, n, s, 0) # level

def ps_aux(x, n, s, level):
    sum = 0
    for idx, c in enumerate(s):
        print("----> " * level + "C = {}".format(c))
        chk = x - pow(c,n) # test validity 
        if chk > 0:
            ns = s[idx + 1:]
            sum += ps_aux(chk,n,ns, level + 1)
        elif chk == 0:
            print("OK!")
            sum += 1 # one result is found
        else:
            sum += 0 # no valid result
    return sum
```

Try with:

```py
X=10 # 1 solution
N=2
st = list(range(1,int(pow(X,1/float(N))) + 1 )) # generate set of unique numbers
print(str(ps(X, N, st)))

X=25 # 2 solutions [3,4], [5]
N=2
st = list(range(1,int(pow(X,1/float(N))) + 1 )) # generate set of unique numbers
print(str(ps(X, N, st)))
```